# ¿Como contar, ordenar y almacenar en variables, los datos que me traigo de la BD?

Tags: php, mysql

Buenos dias, tengo una pequeña consulta... tengo esta tabla en Mysql

Este es mi query:

```
SELECT  at_ce.condicion, 
        COUNT(at_ce.id) AS cantidad_condicion, 
        gpr.grupo_programa, 
        COUNT(gpr.id_programa) AS cantidad_grupo_programa
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es contar todos los "RESERVADOS", "CONFIRMADOS", "NO PASO CONSULTAS"  y en grupo programa "CLUB DE LA SALUD" "INSTITUCIONAL/PRIVADOS" "CIA. SEGUROS/CONVENIOS".

Algo asi

$Reservado = Cantidad_reservado;
$Consultas = cantidad_consultas;
...

Queria hacerlo primero con un FOR y luego un switch algo asi

```
$c = count($resultado);
    for($i = 0, $i < $c; $i++){
        switch($resultado[$i]->GRUPO2){
            case 'CONDICION':
            switch($resultado[$i]->GRUPO1){
                case('RESERVADO'): SUMA DE TODOS LOS RESERVADOS;
                break;
            };
            break;
            case 'GRUPO_PROGRAMA':
            switch($resultado[$i]->GRUPO1){
                case('CLUB DE LA SALUD'): SUMA DE TODOS LOS CLUB DE LA SALUD;
                break;
            };
            break;
        }
    }
```

La consulta SQL que realizo es la siguiente:

```
SELECT at_ce.condicion, COUNT(at_ce.id) AS cantidad_condicion, gpr.grupo_programa, COUNT(gpr.id_programa) AS cantidad_grupo_programa
```

Pero nosé como establecer sus variables, alguien por favor podría orientarme.. Muchas gracias ante mano.

Comment: No llego a comprender bien que querés hacer. ¿Querés contar todo y ordenarlos? ¿El orden es según su ID o su cantidad en forma ascendente /descendente?

Comment: Si, quiero que se sumen todo lo relacionado a "RESERVAS", etc. y luego mostrarlo :/

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar no veo ninguna consulta en le código, intuyo que estará la consulta almacenada en $resultado.

Yo te recomendaría filtrar directamente en la consulta que realizás, por ejemplo:

```
$reservados = tu_funcion_de_consultar("SELECT * FROM {tabla} WHERE condicion = 'RESERVADO'");
$confirmados = tu_funcion_de_consultar("SELECT * FROM {tabla} WHERE condicion = 'CONFIRMADOS'");
$no_paso_consultas = tu_funcion_de_consultar("SELECT * FROM {tabla} WHERE condicion = 'NO PASO CONSULTAS'");
```

Pongo tu_funcion_de_consultar porque en lo personal yo prefiero armar mi propia función para realizar las consultas a la base de datos en lugar de las funciones propias de php.

¿Te sirvió para algo?

Sigo acá para seguir el hilo.

Si justamente lo que no quieres es realizar varias consultas, podrías intentar esto, lo pongo completo.

```
$consulta = ('SELECT  at_ce.condicion, 
              COUNT(at_ce.id) AS cantidad_condicion, gpr.grupo_programa, 
              COUNT(gpr.id_programa) AS cantidad_grupo_programa
              FROM at_cons_externa at_ce
              INNER JOIN gen_programa gpr ON at_ce.id_programa = gpr.id_programa
              GROUP BY at_ce.condicion, gpr.grupo_programa');

$devuelve = array();

#Realizamos la consulta y verificamos errores
if(!$respuesta = $db->query($consulta)){
    die('Hubo un error al consultar la base de datos: [' . $db->error . '] <br>' . $consulta);
}

while ($row = $respuesta->fetch_assoc()){
    if ($array){
        $devuelve[] = $row;
    } else {
        $devuelve = implode("",$row);
    }
}

foreach ($devuelve as $dato){
    if ($dato['condicion'] = "RESERVADOS"){ 
        array_push($reservados, $dato);
    } elseif ($dato['condicion'] = "CONFIRMADOS"){
        array_push($confirmados, $dato);
    }

}
```

Comment: Este es mi query "SELECT  at_ce.condicion, 
        COUNT(at_ce.id) AS cantidad_condicion, 
        gpr.grupo_programa, 
        COUNT(gpr.id_programa) AS cantidad_grupo_programa" todo lo traigo con uno solo, es para no hacer varias consultas en un mismo modelo, solo quiero ordenarlos por los nombres.

Comment: No me salio :/, sale error sobre un array.

Comment: Si podés ver el error copiámelo así lo revisamos! :)

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la solución... bueno lo dejo si alguien lo necesita.

```
    $Confirmado = 0;
    $Reservado = 0;
    $No_Consulta = 0;
    $Observado = 0;

    $Institucional = 0;
    $Club_salud = 0;
    $Madre_ni = 0;
    $Cia_seg = 0;

    foreach ($query as $key) {
        for ($i=0; $i < count($key->anio) ; $i++) { 
            switch ($key->condicion) {
                case 'CONFIRMADO':
                    $Confirmado = $Confirmado + $key->cantidad_condicion;
                    break;
                case 'RESERVADO':
                    $Reservado = $Reservado + $key->cantidad_condicion;
                    break;
                case 'NO PASO CONSULTA':
                    $No_Consulta = $No_Consulta + $key->cantidad_condicion;
                    break;
                case 'OBSERVADO':
                    $Observado = $Observado + $key->cantidad_condicion;
                    break;
                default:
                    echo "";
                    break;
            }
            switch ($key->grupo_programa) {
                case 'INSTITUCIONAL/PRIVADOS':
                    $Institucional = $Institucional + $key->cantidad_grupo_programa;
                    break;
                case 'CLUB DE LA SALUD':
                    $Club_salud = $Club_salud + $key->cantidad_grupo_programa;
                    break;
                case 'MADRE NIÑO':
                    $Madre_ni = $Madre_ni + $key->cantidad_grupo_programa;
                    break;
                case 'CIA. SEGUROS/CONVENIOS':
                    $Cia_seg = $Cia_seg + $key->cantidad_grupo_programa;
                    break;
                default:
                    echo "";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    echo $Confirmado;
```

Gracias por su tiempo.